# How can a Kubernetes pod connect to database which is running in the same local network (outside the cluster) as the host?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, kubernetes, calico

I have a Kubernetes cluster (K8s) running in a physical server A (internal network IP 192.168.200.10) and a PostgreSQL database running in another physical server B (internal network IP 192.168.200.20). How can my Java app container (pod) running in the K8s be able to connect to the PostgreSQL DB in server B?

OS: Ubuntu v16.04
Docker 18.09.7
Kubernetes v1.15.4
Calico v3.8.2
Pod base image: openjdk:8-jre-alpine

I have tried following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services) to create a service and endpoint

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: external-postgres
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 5432
   targetPort: 5432
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: external-postgres
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 192.168.200.20
   ports:
     - port: 5432
```

And had my JDBC connection string as: jdbc:postgresql://external-postgres/MY_APPDB , but it doesn't work. The pod cannot ping server B or telnet the DB using the said internal IP or ping external-postgres service name. I do not wish to use "hostNetwork: true" or connect server B via a public IP.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the issue is due to the K8s network conflict with the server local network (192.168.200.x)
subnet.
During the K8s cluster initialization 

`kubadmin init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`

The **CIDR 192.168.0.0/16** IP range must be change to something else eg. 10.123.0.0/16

And this IP range must be also changed in the calico.yaml file before applying the Calico plugin:

```
# The default IPv4 pool to create on startup if none exists. Pod IPs will be
# chosen from this range. Changing this value after installation will have
# no effect. This should fall within `--cluster-cidr`.
  - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
    value: "10.123.0.0/16"
```

Can now ping and telnet server B after reset and re-init the K8s cluster with the different CIDR.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can replace `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` without re-spawning K8s cluster via `kubeadm` builder tool, maybe it can be useful in some circumstances.

Remove current Calico [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) plugin installation, eg.:

`$ kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml`

Install [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/) CNI addon, supplying `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` parameter with a desired value:

`$ curl -k https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml --output some_file.yaml && sed -i "s~$old_ip~$new_ip~" some_file.yaml && kubectl apply -f some_file.yaml`

Re-spin [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/) pods:

`$ kubectl delete pod --selector=k8s-app=kube-dns -n kube-system`

Wait until CoreDNS pods obtain IP address from a new network CIDR pool.